# Targeting second span in li element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<li>
<span>Hi</span>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<span>Bye</span>
</li>
```

How can I target the second `span`?  I don't want to access the third child of `li`, but the second span in `li`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to get the second `span` in the `li` element.

```
$("li span").eq(1)
```

`eq()` will return a jQuery object with a reference to the second span. So you can continue calling jQuery methods on it.

If you rather get the HTML element of the second span you could use this instead:

```
$("li span")[1];
```

Comment: @HommerSmith: Has this helped or do you still have issues with this? If you do, feel free to post the markup you are working with for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use a jquery selector with CSS nth-child.

```
$('li span:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following selector:

```
$('li').children('span').eq(1);
```

Comment: This will not use the native querySelectorAll function.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a shot : Add jquery reference and use this script

```
<script>
    $("li span:nth-child(2)").append("<span> - 2nd!</span>");
</script>
```